# AWS Cloudwatch alarm from Account A unable to publish to SNS topic in Account B

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

Just when I thought I had cross org permissions sorted I am stuck with CloudWatch alarms and SNS. 
Have tried several options but am not able to get the access policy right on the SNS topic. Cloudwatch and SNS topic are in the same region but different accounts in the same org. Surely I don't need lambda in the middle to manage this, AWS have cross org support for CloudWatch now. Few options below I have tried.

SNS Topic is in account A = 1111111111
Cloudwatch alarm is in account B = 22222222

Option 1 - Account B has publish rights to the SNS topic

```
{
    "Sid": "__console_pub_0",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": [
        "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root",
        "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root"
      ]
    },
    "Action": "SNS:Publish",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:alerttopicname"
  }
```

Option 2 - Gave the Cloudwatch service access to publish to the SNS topic

```
 {
        "Sid": "Allow_Publish_Alarms",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal":
        {
            "Service": [
                "cloudwatch.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "sns:Publish",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:alerttopicname"
    }
```

Option 3 - Cross org permissions, I updated the IAM role in account B too

```
 {
       "Sid": "CrossOrgPublish01",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
          "AWS": "*"
       },
       "Action": "SNS:Publish",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:alerttopicname",
       "Condition": {
          "ArnLike": {
             "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:222222222222:alarm:*"
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3 is correct. However, this is **not IAM role** in Acc B. It should be added as a statement in **a topic policy of Acc A**.

Assuming you have a default topic policy in Acc A, after adding the new statement, you would have:

#### SNS topic policy in ACC A

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:Receive",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:alerttopicname",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "111111111111"
        }
      }
    },       
    {
       "Sid": "CrossOrgPublish01",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
          "AWS": "*"
       },
       "Action": "sns:Publish",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:alerttopicname",
       "Condition": {
          "ArnLike": {
             "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:222222222222:alarm:*"
          }
       }
    }

  ]
}
```

Comment: sorry yes to clarify the policy is applied to the SNS topic, not an IAM role.  I will capture the policy you have above, it looks very similar to what I am troubleshooting currently as SourceOwner as suggested.

Comment: @RobQlder Just dont worry about the message "This IAM user does not have permission to access the SNS topics and subscriptions for this account.". The message is about your IAM user, not the service. Ignore it, and check by actually triggering the alarm, from OK into ALARM state.

Comment: ahh ok that explains the bizzare IAM user ref.  The other indicators I use haven't changed either.  CloudWatch alarm in account 2 is OK status but says it can't verify SNS as it is in another account.
I have cross org cloudwatch configured.  When I look at this alarm via the console in account 1 the status is ok but it says "SNS topic not found".
I might try and trigger this alarm to see what happens and what is logged.  I have tested the SNS via direct publishing.

Comment: @RobQlder Just test manually. You can trigger the alarm using [set-alarm-state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/set-alarm-state.html). It must change state. So it only triggers from a state change OK->ALARM. Being in alarm state does not trigger it.

Comment: Is AWS serious right now!!    Ok so this works, many thanks to Marcin and mokugo-devops for helping me.  So the console GUI still says in multiple locations there is an issue either "topic not found" or "This IAM user does not have permission to access the SNS topics and subscriptions for this account.".  But it actually does work.... and probably did hours ago!!!  Ok ok so today I learned not to trust console error messages and test features out before assuming they don't work.  Thanks to you for your patience.

Comment: @RobQlder Glad it got sorted out. I learned the hard way to ignore many things what console says unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 1):

**Option 3** should work as per the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html#sns-allow-cloudwatch-alarm-to-publish-to-topic-in-another-account) but you said they're in the same region.

In this they're different regions. One is us-east-1 one is us-east-2. It is important for these to share the same region.

Also to validate option 3 should be an SNS topic policy, not an IAM user or role.

To modify this, go to the SNS topic in the console, select edit, then add to the statement in the "Access Policy" section.

Comment: hmm I was sure I created both in North Virginia.  Obviously not - let me clean this up so they are both in us-east1 and try again.

Comment: ohh and check this [AWS doco](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-receive-sns-for-alarm-trigger/) out for option 2.

Comment: Ah that would be the topic policy, but this would only grant access from CloudWatch in the same account

Comment: Ok so both SNS and Cloudwatch are in us-east-1, I updated policy option 3 to correct my typo.  Still no joy, CloudWatch tells me "This IAM user does not have permission to access the SNS topics and subscriptions for this account."

Comment: Update it to Option 3

Comment: yep that is what I did, still no joy

Comment: Right so your SNS topic now has that access policy? Try updating the condition in the policy to "AWS:SourceOwner": instead with your account id as the value

Comment: starting to think this is not supported, even tried this which is option one and three combined.
`{
       "Sid": "CrossOrgPublish01",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::1111111111111:root",
            "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root"
          ]
       },
       "Action": "SNS:Publish",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:11111111111:snstopicname",
       "Condition": {
          "ArnLike": {
             "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:22222222222:alarm:*"
          }
       }
    }`

Comment: How about ```{
 "Sid": "CrossOrgPublish01",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Principal": {
  "AWS": "*"
 },
 "Action": "SNS:Publish",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:11111111111:snstopicname",
 "Condition": {
  "StringEquals": {
   "AWS:SourceOwner": "22222222222"
  }
 }
}```

Comment: will try your now.  this just failed which uses SourceAccount `{
          "Sid": "CrossOrgPublish01",
          "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": { 
            "Service": "cloudwatch.amazonaws.com" 
          },
          "Action": "sns:Publish",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:11111111111:SNSalert",
          "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
              "AWS:SourceAccount": "222222222"
            }       
          }
        }`

Comment: ohh man seriously it works, check the policy in the answer.  Just so you know I think option 3 was fine as you suggested but the damn console reports it as broken even though it works.  Many thanks for helping me.

Comment: Glad I helped fix for you :)